# Google analytics service provider leads

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

currently working with Google analytics to get a list of companies based on GA's Service providers (which after a filter of "default ones" I can determine the leads). Now I would like to be able to get an overview of urls visited per lead. I can't find any way to get those service providers linked to visited urls in the API.

P.S. only interested in results of last 24 hours so I don't need full histories.

Answer (score 0):

I would just request [ga:pagePath](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath), [ga:networkLocation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=geo_network&jump=ga_networklocation) dimensions ga:pageViews metric then add a [filter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) on with ga:date = today.  The filter will ensure that you only get data back for today.

This should give you a list of the Network domans and what pages they viewed today.

There is a problem with this it can take a while for google to process the data i have read any where from 4 - 8 hours.  I normaly filter on yesterday that way i'm almost always sure that all the data was processed.  You could try with the realTime api but then there isnt much data there and there are a limited number of dimensions and metrics you can select from it. I'm not even sure that what you are looking for is available.

Comment: it is no problem if I have to use like yesterday so I'm sure all data is processed